# Java program temperature sensor simulator

Tags: java

I'm writing a program whose topic was closed earlier and I'm having trouble with it. I wrote the code though.Also I want to use the random code in which if I chose a season it has to randomly select numbers between like 20 and 40. The output doesn't show me the first, last, highest and lowest temperature generated and neither the sum nor average.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempSim {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int simulations = 0, InputTemp = 0, choice = 0;
double firstTemp = 0, lastTemp = 0, lowestTemp= 0, highestTemp = 0, sum = 0 ;

 System.out.println("Select Season");
 System.out.println("Press 1 for winter");
 System.out.println("Press 2 for spring");
 System.out.println("Press 3 for summer");
 System.out.println("Press 4 for fall");
 System.out.println("Press 5 to exit");
  choice = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter number of simulations:");
    simulations = input.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < simulations; i++)
            if (choice == 1){
        while( InputTemp > 20 && InputTemp < 40){
    System.out.print("Enter Temperature: ");
       InputTemp = input.nextInt();
       sum += InputTemp;
       firstTemp = InputTemp;
       lastTemp = InputTemp;
       if (InputTemp > highestTemp){
           highestTemp = InputTemp;
       }
    if (InputTemp < lowestTemp){
           lowestTemp = InputTemp;
    }
}

    if (choice == 2){
        while( InputTemp > 40 && InputTemp < 70){
            System.out.print("Enter Temperature: ");
               InputTemp = input.nextInt();
               sum += InputTemp;
               firstTemp = InputTemp;
               lastTemp = InputTemp;
               if (InputTemp > highestTemp){
                   highestTemp = InputTemp;
               }
            if (InputTemp < lowestTemp){
                   lowestTemp = InputTemp;
            }
        }




            if (choice == 3){
                while( InputTemp > 70 && InputTemp < 90){
                    System.out.print("Enter Temperature: ");
                       InputTemp = input.nextInt();
                       sum += InputTemp;
                       firstTemp = InputTemp;
                       lastTemp = InputTemp;
                       if (InputTemp > highestTemp){
                           highestTemp = InputTemp;
                       }
                    if (InputTemp < lowestTemp){
                           lowestTemp = InputTemp;
                    }
                }


if (choice == 4){
while( InputTemp > 40 && InputTemp < 60){
System.out.print("Enter Temperature: ");
InputTemp = input.nextInt();             
sum += InputTemp;
firstTemp = InputTemp;
lastTemp = InputTemp;
if (InputTemp > highestTemp){
highestTemp = InputTemp;
}
 if (InputTemp < lowestTemp)
lowestTemp = InputTemp;
                            }


else
                                                             System.out.println("First Temperature: " +firstTemp); 
                                                             System.out.println("Last Temperature: " +lastTemp);
                                                             System.out.println("Lowest Temperature: " +lowestTemp);
                                                             System.out.println("Highest Temperature: " +highestTemp);
                                                             System.out.println("Sum: " +sum);
                                                             System.out.println("Average: " +sum/simulations);
                                            }
                    }
            }
       }
     }


else

System.out.println("The program will now exit");

}}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear and the code you're providing has syntax errors. Please read the guidelines for posting a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user3326710 but your `while` loops are not going to be executed even once, because your `InputTemp` is zero initially

Comment: This isn't a question. Also, you have curly braces in all the wrong places in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry I should've been clearer. Is the while loop correct to generate the simulator

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int 
    simulations = 0, 
    InputTemp   = 0, 
    choice      = 0;

double
    firstTemp   = 0, 
    lastTemp    = 0,
    lowestTemp  = 0, 
    highestTemp = 0, 
    sum         = 0;

 System.out.println("Select Season");
 System.out.println("Press 1 for winter");
 System.out.println("Press 2 for spring");
 System.out.println("Press 3 for summer");
 System.out.println("Press 4 for fall");
 System.out.println("Press 5 to exit");

 choice = input.nextInt();

 if(choice==5) System.exit(0);

 System.out.println("Enter number of simulations:");

 simulations = input.nextInt();

 for(int i = 1; i <= simulations; i++){

 System.out.println("Starting simulation " + i);


if (choice == 1){
                  do{
                       System.out.print("Enter Temperature: ");
                       InputTemp = input.nextInt();
                       sum += InputTemp;
                       firstTemp = InputTemp;
                       lastTemp = InputTemp;
                       if (InputTemp > highestTemp)
                           highestTemp = InputTemp;       
                       if (InputTemp < lowestTemp)
                           lowestTemp = InputTemp;
                       }while( InputTemp > 20 && InputTemp < 40);   //end while
                }//end if


if (choice == 2){
                  do{
                       System.out.print("Enter Temperature: ");
                       InputTemp = input.nextInt();
                       sum += InputTemp;
                       firstTemp = InputTemp;
                       lastTemp = InputTemp;
                       if (InputTemp > highestTemp)
                           highestTemp = InputTemp;               
                       if (InputTemp < lowestTemp)
                           lowestTemp = InputTemp;
                    }while( InputTemp > 40 && InputTemp < 70);     //end while
                }//end if


if (choice == 3){
                  do{
                       System.out.print("Enter Temperature: ");
                       InputTemp = input.nextInt();
                       sum += InputTemp;
                       firstTemp = InputTemp;
                       lastTemp = InputTemp;
                       if (InputTemp > highestTemp)
                           highestTemp = InputTemp;                       
                       if (InputTemp < lowestTemp)
                           lowestTemp = InputTemp;
                    }while( InputTemp > 70 && InputTemp < 90);     //end while
                }//end if


if (choice == 4){
                  do{
                        System.out.print("Enter Temperature: ");
                        InputTemp = input.nextInt();             
                        sum += InputTemp;
                        firstTemp = InputTemp;
                        lastTemp = InputTemp;
                        if (InputTemp > highestTemp)
                            highestTemp = InputTemp;                    
                        if (InputTemp < lowestTemp)
                            lowestTemp = InputTemp;
                    }while( InputTemp > 40 && InputTemp < 60);     //end while
                }//end if   



}//end for

 System.out.println("First Temperature: " +firstTemp); 
 System.out.println("Last Temperature: " +lastTemp);
 System.out.println("Lowest Temperature: " +lowestTemp);
 System.out.println("Highest Temperature: " +highestTemp);
 System.out.println("Sum: " +sum);
 System.out.println("Average: " +sum/simulations);


 System.out.println("The program will now exit");

}//end main
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation of what you changed and why? Just dumping the code with the errors corrected won't help all that much.

Comment: @Stendika I just corrected braces, replaced `while` with `do-while` and added option 5 :)

Comment: it can further be improved by including `Math.random()` but I leave it to the author

Comment: How do use Math.random(). I corrected the code but it kept asking to enter temperature while starting simulation. Each simulation has to generate random numbers. Do I use math.random in a while loop?

Comment: You should remove these two lines `System.out.print("Enter Temperature: "); InputTemp = input.nextInt();` from all 4 cases, and put `InputTemp = <some scaling factor> * Math.random();` instead

Comment: Do I have to have to make up a scaling factor or is it a real variable?

Comment: see this link to make a proper statement for generating a random number within a given range: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: Another problem I ran the program and it's not simulated properly. My professor tells me to use a do while loop so i select the options and simulations stop, it should go back to the menu.

Comment: /Select Season
Press 1 for winter
Press 2 for spring
Press 3 for summer
Press 4 for fall
Press 5 to exit
2
Enter number of simulations:
7
Starting simulation 1
Starting simulation 2
Starting simulation 3
Starting simulation 4
Starting simulation 5
Starting simulation 6
Starting simulation 7
First Temperature: 70.0
Last Temperature: 70.0
Lowest Temperature: 0.0
Highest Temperature: 70.0
Sum: 8753.0
Average: 1250.4285714285713
The program will now exit